# Error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I am newbie at analysis services. When I try to execute ssis package on command prompt with dtexec command, I get the error :

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll Version 13.0.0.0

I tried few solutions which I found internet but they didn't work.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

Edit 20180604: [Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2016 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4135048/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2016-sp2) fixes the issue.

Pre-20180604 answer: There's now a workaround for this bug, published [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1949923.aspx):

> There is a bug, it will probably be corrected in SP2 CU1 which I've
>   been told will be released at the end of the month. We got a
>   workaround suggestion from MS, but that was not enough.
>
> In short: The provided workaround does not work as is, but I found out
>   what more to do so now it works on the server with SP2
>
> Longer: The provided workaround does not work as is because it does
>   register the correct assembly and the correct version (v14), but when
>   the package is run it will still search for the previous version v13. I
>   have tested and this is the case even if I have SP2 on my laptop,
>   rebuild all in the SSIS project and deploy – it will still be v13 that
>   is search for. It does not help to register v13 of the assembly, since
>   that version does not have a method that is called, so that will just
>   lead to other error messages.
>
> The resolution I made on the server is to put in a binding redirect in
>   the .NET machine.config so that v14 is used even though v13 is searched
>   for.
>
> Step-by-step I did, run from an elevated CMD:
>
> 1: Register the assembly: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll"
>
> You should get message one assembly successfully registered in GAC.
>
> 2: (Optional) Verify registration:
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /l Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI
>
> You should see message it is version 14.0.0.0 registered
>
> 3: Configure version redirect in machine.config (be careful when
>   editing!!)
>
> File to edit:
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config"
>
> The element to add content to is
>
> configuration/runtime
>
> On the server I fixed it on, this element was completely empty, i.e.
>
> ```
> <runtime/>
> ```
>
> If it is not empty, of course keep what’s in the element and add the
>   assemblyBinding element seen below.
>
> Change/add so that the whole element contains this instead:
>
> ```
> <runtime>
>   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>     <dependentAssembly>
>       <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI"
>                         publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"
>                         culture="neutral"/>
>       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.0.0"
>                        newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
>     </dependentAssembly>
>   </assemblyBinding>
> </runtime>
> ```
>
> 5: Save the file. The package should now work.
>
> When a fix in CU1 is installed, these steps should be done:
>
> 1: Remove the above added assemblyBinding element and save the file
>
> 2: Remove the dll that was added to the GAC: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /u Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI

In my server, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll" was version 13, so in step 1 v13 was being registered (you can check the version by right clicking/Properties and then clicking on Details tab).

To solve this I:

1. Unregistered v13 with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /u Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI
2. Copied v14 from a computer with VS installed to "C:\Program Files\"
3. For step 1, I executed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll"

The steps when the fix arrives remain the same (with the addition of deleting "C:\Program Files\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll").

Note: if you're running your packages in 32-bit instead of 64-bit, the machine.config that needs to be edited is the one located at c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Answer (score 2):

SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi includes Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll, but not Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdmomdClientUI.dll.

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdmomdClientUI.dll is included in SQL Management Studio, but version 13.0.1700.441 that I had as a drop in replacement failed due a new method being invoked, and I have not been able to locate a matching SQL 2016 SP2 version. Presumably awaiting a hotfix from Microsoft now.

Comment: hi, I am having issues with SQL 2017, my package throws: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=19.42.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Any tips are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientUI.dll* from MS SQL Server Feature Pack component *SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi*.

Presumably you have SQL server 2016, so you can get it from the [SQL 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676).